# Inserting Data in Windows Azure Blobs and HDInsight?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Windows Azure and HDInsight so please forgive me if my question is naive.......Is inserting data in HDInsight and Windows Azure Blobs are one and the same thing???

Please advice on the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The blob storage is used as a backing store for HDInsight. When you setup a cluster you have to give it a reference to at least one blob store account. You can then see the contents of that account through the wasb:// protocol in HDInsight.